# ls-remote --heads origin vs ls-remote . "refs/remotes/*"

Tags: git

What is the difference between

```
git ls-remote --heads origin
```

and

```
git ls-remote . "refs/remotes/*"
```

?

The `--heads origin` version takes a while to run, I guess it's updating the references from the origin. The `. "refs/remotes/*"` runs instantly.

I'd like to use these lines to git grep remote heads as in the expression below. Which is the right one to use?

```
git grep "expression" $(git ls-remote . "refs/remotes/*" | grep -v HEAD | cut -f 2)
```

Is it possible that the `--heads origin` can return hashes which are not available locally, thus git-grep wouldn't be able to complete? In this case I guess the right one to use would be `. "refs/remotes/*"` with a fetch all first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `git ls-remote . "refs/remotes/*"` the dot means you query your local repository to get the data.

As you wrote if you use `git ls-remote --heads origin` nobody guarantees that the returned hashes will be accessible locally.
So I think your `git fetch` and then using `git ls-remote . "refs/remotes/*"` is the safest option.